# How can I change sublayers of animation layer when using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, core-animation

I want to change the parent layer's sublayers dynamically when using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool. I noticed that  sublayers is an animatable property accordingto 《Core Animation Programming Guide》, but still can't figure it out how to achieve that. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool, but in general it works like following Code. It will show an animation when removing and adding at the new parent layer. The action identifiers if you'd like to change them are `kCAOnOrderIn` and `kCAOnOrderOut`.

```
CALayer *layerToMove = ....; 
CALayer *newParent = ...;
[CATransaction begin];
[layerToMove removeFromSuperLayer];
[newParent addSublayer:layerToMove];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: What kind of animation would you like to see?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mahal. I want to change the animation layer periodically when using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool to export the animations as a video. My work around is, I added all the animation layers to parent layer, and set them to hidden, and set the wanted layer visible according to the time